# error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp .Default.props" was not found while trying to publish mixed project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2022, vcxproj

I have .NET 7 mixed project with C++ managed and C dlls. I'm using Visual Studio 22 Enterprise.
When I try to publish the project using the command **dotnet publish -c Release --self-contained -p:PublishSingleFile=true** I get erron on the Managed C++ project - *error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found*  for the line in the VCXproj: **<Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props/>**

Searching for this problem - I looked what other people mentioned but I could not find the **VCTargetsPath **not in the environement variables,not in the registry and looking on the installation of Visual Studio - it is installed under **C:\Program Files**\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise and not C:\Program Files (x86).
I have no idea what's missing.